# HTML5 and dhtmlxForm

Tags: html, dhtmlx

There are In HTML5 some dhtmlxForm inputs that I need to use which I haven't found in documentation, for example :

```
<input type="time" name="usr_time">
```

[Like here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_time)
How can I add them to my dhtmlxForm and use them as its items?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such item type.
You can create a custom item according to the [next article](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/form__custom_item.html)